# Why doesn't the Hafele-Keating experiment settle the twin paradox?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

Why doesn't the [Hafele-Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment) settle the twin paradox? It is my understanding that clocks were used, and that the shifts matched the calculations. Doesn't this settle the twin paradox if we replace humans with clocks, implying that the travelling twin is the one who age less?

Comment: Paradoxes are teaching tools. They are trying to make you "unlearn" false thinking patterns. In this case they were trying to teach you not to use the Lorentz transformation when you were required to use the Poincare transformation. I don't think that the twin paradox is a good teaching tool of its kind since it seems to mostly reinforce poor mental habits about special relativity, but that's just my personal opinion about how to teach, nothing more.

Comment: I think it is the ideal problem to introduce the spacetime interval as a way to _avoid_ those poor mental habits and get the right answer instantly.  I just don't like the label "paradox"; people take it the wrong way, as we see so often.

Answer (score 6):

The twin paradox is not a thing to be settled. There is nothing weird in the mathematics. It is called a paradox only because it gives us a weird feeling in the gut. Otherwise, as a thing that can be mathematically worked out, it is a direct prediction of Einstein's theories of relativity, and there is no problem there to settle.